# Different css modules with same class names overwrite each other

Tags: css, webpack, css-loader, css-modules

I'm using webpack and try to use css modules for my theming, for example:

```css
<style lang="scss" module="theme1">
  .header {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<style lang="scss" module="theme2">
  .header {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

However, both .header tags get the same localIdentName from css-loader and because of that the second theme overrides the other everytime.
My loader chain: vue-loader, css-loader, sass-loader
My current localIdentName: `'[local]_[hash:base64:5]'` (neither path nor name result in anything, I just wish there was some sort of [value] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's because custom inject names were broken during the v14 -> v15 upgrade from `vue-loader`.

Heres the issue on GitHub with more details:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1578

Temporary solution (put this in the module options of `css-loader`):

```
{
  localIdentName: '[module]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
  getLocalIdent(context, localIdentName, localName) {
    const { resourceQuery, resourcePath } = context;
    const { index, module } = loaderUtils.parseQuery(resourceQuery);

    const selector = loaderUtils.interpolateName(context, localIdentName, {
      context: context.rootContext,
      content: resourcePath + resourceQuery + localName,
    })
      .replace(/\[local\]/gi, localName)
      .replace(/\[module\]/gi, typeof module === 'boolean' ? '' : module)
      .replace(/\[index\]/gi, index)
      .replace(new RegExp('[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-_\u00A0-\uFFFF]', 'g'), '-')
      .replace(/^((-?[0-9])|--)/, '_$1');

    return selector;
  },
}
```